# Uniformly Bounded and Weakly compactness.

Tags: real-analysis

Is a uniformly bounded sequence weakly compact in $l_1$? If Yes, What is the reason?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Is this true in $\ell^p$ if $1 < p < \infty$ or if $p= \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**. A weakly convergent sequence in $\ell^1$ is also strongly convergent,  since this Banach space has the [Schur property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property). If the answer were yes, then bounded closed sets in $\ell^1$ would be compact, which is false.

A concrete counterexample of a bounded sequence in $\ell^1$ that has no weakly convergent subsequence is given by $x_n$ where $x_n \in \ell^1$ is the element that has 1 in position $n$ and 0 elsewhere. Consider first the functionals $f_k(z) = z_k$ for $z \in \ell^1$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_k(x_n) = 0$ for all $k$. Thus if there is any weakly convergent subsequence of the $x_n$, its weak limit would have to be the zero sequence. But for the functional $g(z) = \sum_j z_j$, obviously $g(x_n) = 1$ for all $n$. Therefore no subsequence can converge weakly.

Answer (score 1):

*If a sequence converges strongly, then it converges weakly as well. However,bounded and weakly closed sets are weakly compact so as a consequence every convex bounded closed set is weakly compact. As a consequence of the principle of uniform boundedness, every weakly convergent sequence is bounded.*

Comment: This is a very different situation.

Comment: Now i have edited my ans.

Comment: The closed unit ball of $l^{1}$ is not weakly compact.

Comment: @John Please state the assumptions